# Vercel not following/finding folder structure when serving static website

Tags: html, css, vercel, static-files

I have a static html website that I am deploying using vercel. link can be found [here](https://qlick-website-5ed0y11v0-karanunewton.vercel.app/). However, there are some pages that return `404` yet the directory and index files are present.

Here is my folder structure.

[image: folder structure]

As you can see, there is the root folder containing `index.html`. A directory called `sms-solutions` and inside it, a directory called `bulk-and-premium` which contains `index.html`.

The linking of my CSS files in `sms-solutions/index.html` are as follows.

```html
...
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />
...
```

The location of the CSS file can be seen in the folder structure image above, i.e `sms-solutions/css/style.css`.
However, my console shows that Vercel is trying to find the CSS file in the root of the project

My question comes in 3 parts.

1. Why can I not view the content in the index file when I visit `sms-solutions/bulk-and-premium` or `sms-solutions/bulk-and-premium/index.html`? (I see a 404 Page not found error)
2. Why can't vercel find my static (CSS) files?
3. How can I be able to fix above mentioned issues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The nested pages were setting the links relative to the root instead of their parent folder. You can solve this by adding a `vercel.json` config with the contents

```json
{
  "trailingSlash": true
}
```

The [trailingSlash](https://vercel.com/docs/concepts/projects/project-configuration#trailingslash) config will ensure that the path always has a trailing slash to signal that you are in a folder so the relative link references will work